# How to move a class property without breaking a web service contract?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, wsdl

I recently made some changes to a WCF WebService that broke my web service contract.  I'm hoping there's a way that I can generate the same/similar WSDL that is backwards compatible (currently, UpdateTypes is always = 0/None no matter what I set it to in my client code)

*My code below only shows the sections that are pertinent to the issue.*

This was the way my code looked like originally:

```
public enum UpdateTypes
{
    None = 0,
    Insert = 1,
    Update = 2,
    Delete = 3
}

[DataContract()]
public class BaseEntity
{
    [DataMember()]
    public UpdateTypes UpdateType {get; set;}
}

public class User : BaseEntity
{
    //...other properties and methods
}
```

Which generated a WSDL that looked like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="BaseEntity">
    <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UpdateType" type="tns:UpdateTypes" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="BaseEntity" nillable="true" type="tns:BaseEntity" />
<xs:simpleType name="UpdateTypes">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:enumeration value="None" />
       <xs:enumeration value="Insert" />
       <xs:enumeration value="Update" />
       <xs:enumeration value="Delete" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="UpdateTypes" nillable="true" type="tns:UpdateTypes" />
```

And this is what I changed my class code to which broke my Web Service contract:

```
public class User : IUpdateable
{
    [DataMember()]
    public UpdateTypes UpdateType { get; set; }

    //...other properties and methods
}
```

because it changed the WSDL to look like this (notice that the BaseEntity section is now missing):

```
<xs:simpleType name="UpdateTypes">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:enumeration value="None" />
       <xs:enumeration value="Insert" />
       <xs:enumeration value="Update" />
       <xs:enumeration value="Delete" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="UpdateTypes" nillable="true" type="tns:UpdateTypes" />
```

This causes the UpdateType to always be 0 when it gets to the newly updated WCF Service Endpoint application.

Comment: Your revised code doesn't reference `BaseEntity`, it references `BaseUser`....?

Comment: It's a typo and I removed - it shouldn't be inheriting at all (although it may inherit in the future)

Answer (score 0):

You can direct WCF to use a custom WSDL which matches your original contract, although it is not trivial.  Here's a microsoft example adding documentation to the WSDL:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717040(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm not sure that would help me because I want any new implementations of the service to use the new/current wsdl but I don't want to break any current implementations that are still using the old wsdl.